# mod_rewrite with optional trailing slash (No Content displaying)

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my website. I have mod_rewrite enabled (Below is the code):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/?$ index.php?ToDo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When accessing my website with the above .htaccess file contents, viewing the pages with the backslash gone, will show the desired content of each page (organized by conditional statements [Ex. if($_GET['ToDo'] == 'about'){}]).

However, when viewing the page with the trailing slash, it doesn't display the content (organized by conditional statements [Ex. if($_GET['ToDo'] == 'about'){}]). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modified regex:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?ToDo=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Will this also work if I include '&%{QUERY_STRING}' ?

Comment: You don't need `&%{QUERY_STRING}'` since QSA flag does exactly same.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.